# what is the key code for space bar in curses.h

Tags: c, ncurses, curses

I just have a simple question, I cannot find what the key code is for space bar in curses.h.
ex. I know the code for down is KEY_DOWN.
can anyone help?

Comment: Tried normal ascii of " " which is 20 Hex?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no macro for the space key. Just use ' ' to represent a space. You can find a complete list of curses key macros [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/curses.h.html).

Ex.

```
char mychar = ' ';
if (mychar == ' ') {//Do this...}
```

Answer (score 6):

A couple of years late, but since this was the top hit when I was confused, I want to contribute! :-)

What you need to do is to use ord(*c*). For example:

```
c = getch()
if c == ord(' '):
    do_something()
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't find a specific definition in [the POSIX documentation for curses](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/curses.h.html).

Try `' '`.